# Linq Order By Contains List

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a List of ints that `model.SelectedIngredients` and in this example the list contains the values `[15128, 4593,15046,]`. I use this list then as a filter in my Linq query as follows:

```
List<INGREDIENT> selectedIngredients = db.INGREDIENT.Where(i => model.SelectedIngredients.Contains(i.IngredientId)).ToList();
```

However, this sorts the results by IngredientId ascending as default`[4593,15046,15128]`.

What I would like is to get the `selectedIngredients` back in the same order as they are in `model.SelectedIngredients`.

I know I could do it in a for loop but I just wondered if there was a way I could do it within the Linq query?

Thanks

Comment: Does this query run against a database? Do you want the ordering to happen at the database side or does it not matter to you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can acomplish this quite easy by using the index of your list with ids.

```
List<INGREDIENT> selectedIngredients = db.INGREDIENT
                         .Where(i => model.SelectedIngredients.Contains(i.IngredientId))
                         .AsEnumerable()
                         .OrderBy(i => model.SelectedIngredients.IndexOf(i.IngredientId))
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: If the query is to be run against the data base, does LINQ know how to translate `model.SelectedIngredients.IndexOf` to SQL? Maybe you need to do this part in memory?

Comment: I agree with Yacoub.  I think you need to slap an `AsEnumerable` between the `Where` and the `OrderBy`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Absolutely agree!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<INGREDIENT> selectedIngredients = db.INGREDIENT
    .Where(i => model.SelectedIngredients.Contains(i.IngredientId))
    .orderBy(p=>p.Id).ToList();
```

This is the default one. Determine in the first place by which it is sorted and then order by it.